# PHP txt File Manipulations

Tags: php, html, string, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create a simple one page php website that does the following.

Displays data from a txt file and then converts it into links.

(A line from the text file would be so if the line is "TextEdit: 1.9" ApplicationName = TextEdit)

So basically I need to add the url strings together with the application names in the desired locations and then redirect to that page. Hopefully ending up with something like:

Link[urlportion+appname+urlportion]

I am getting my data from a txt file that is formatted in the format of:

```
TextEdit: 1.9 

AppleScript Editor: 2.6 

Arduino: 1.0.5 

TextWrangler: 4.5.3 

etc.
```

I can display the code in my page using:

```
<?php
foreach(glob("log.txt") as $filename) {
$file = $filename;
$contents = file($file);
$string = implode("<br>",$contents);
echo $string;
echo "<br></br>";
}
?>
```

That works beautifully my question is how do I separate the txt file into pieces so I can concatenate it with my url and display it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question will probably be closed because it's too general and you haven't attempted to write any code yet. It's not a good format for this site.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific. Hopefully it is better.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple you can just use a text file and delimit your strings. You're going to need a server-side technology to do this - PHP, ASP.NET, etc. You haven't posted what your server-side technology is, but this can't be done without it.

Comment: So I have to have some sort of server database to be able to do this? The strings should already be delimited by the colon right?

Comment: Nope, you can use a text file. You just need a server-side technology to write to the file. I work with .NET and classic ASP - the concept is very similar to connecting to a database. And yes, the colon is your delimiter.

Comment: Ok I have setup a php server so that I can view .php files. How do I parse the txt file into a table?

Comment: I don't really work in PHP much - but if you Google "php parse text file", that should get you started.